# Snackbar on different dart file

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a ThrowError widget that can be accessed from any page inside my app.
Here is what I have done so far:

**Parent Widget**

My parent widget has a RaisedButton widget that checks if the login info is correct, if not a snackbar message is displayed at the bottom of the page. I have the functionality working with having the RaisedButton widget and snackbar on one file with a GlobalKey assignment. I want to separate the snackbar to its own file so I can use it across my app.

Parent Widget with RaisedButton Widget-

```
          RaisedButton(
            hoverColor: Colors.amber,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              String status = await _submit();
              if(status == "authError") _throwError("Please check your credentials");
              if(status == "networkError") _throwError("No Network Connection");
            },
          ),
```

Parent Widget with _throwError function on the same file as the RaisedButton

```
  void _throwError(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
  }
```

**Desired solution**

ThrowError Class on a different file -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThrowError extends StatelessWidget {

  ThrowError({this.context, this.errMessage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Builder(
      builder: (context) =>
            Scaffold.of(this.context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Show Snackbar'),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            ));
    );
}
```

As of now ThrowError class is showing a lot of errors.

Please advise!

**EDIT after trying Amine Dakhli answer -**

```
RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      String status = await _submit();
                      if(status == "authError") {
                        var throwError = new ThrowError();
                        throwError.showError(context, "test");
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

And this is the ThrowError class with showError function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThrowError {

      showError (BuildContext context,String errMessage) {
        return Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(errMessage),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: First why not put the showsnackbar on a function so you can share among all the widgets. Second you can do what you want with state management linke provider or bloc.

Comment: @loki Could you please elaborate with code examples?  I am a total newbie to Flutter.

Comment: You can put your _throwerror function in a separate file but as function that takes a context and a message and then whenever you want to use it import that file and call that function with the context and the message.

Comment: @AmineDakhli I am kind of getting what you are suggesting. Could you please put it as an answer with a sample of the working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this function in a separate file :

```
showError (context,message) {
  return Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      )
  );
}
```

if you are using a global key as in your case the function should be as follows :

```
showError (key,message) {
  return key.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      )
  );
}
```

and whenever you want to use it just impor that file and call as follows :

```
showError(context,'example message') ; in the case of context 
showError(yourkeyvariable,'message') ; in the case of a global key
```

Comment: I have tried the code above, it gives me an error. I have edited my original post after making the changes you suggested. Could you please check it out? Thanks

Comment: I just tried that and it works fine for me, could you show me what the error message you re receiving says ?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the error to the original post

Comment: The issue is with the Parent widget of the RaisedButton, you mentioned that you are using a Global key so what you could do is replace the context wth the globalkey I am editing the answer to show you how you could do that

Comment: Thanks Amine, Really appreciate it